# Retrieving CallSid for incoming call

Tags: ruby, sinatra, twilio

When my ruby script makes outgoing calls through Twilio, it's a piece of cake for me to *find, output, and reuse* the Call Sid for later as such :

> `@client = Twilio::REST:Client.new account_sid, auth_token`
>
> `call = @client.account.calls.create({ :from=>'INC', :to=>'OUT', :url=>'URL', :method=>'GET'})`
>
> `puts call.sid`

This works fine for outgoing calls that I make myself.

### **The issue is when I try to get the call SID for incoming calls.**

> `get '/greeting' do`
>
> `Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|`
>
> `r.Say 'Hello. Welcome.'`
>
> `r.Gather :numDigits => '1', :action => '/greeting/handle-gather', :method => 'get' do |g|`
>
> > `g.Say 'For X, press 1. For Y, press 2. For Z, press 3.'`
>
> `end`
>
> `end.text`

---

> `puts Twilio::TwiML::Request.CallSid`
>
> `CallSid = incoming_Cid`
>
> `end`

The incoming_Cid is then stored in a MYSQL database for later. I'm not sure if `Twilio::TwiML::Request.CallSid` is the correct way to get the request parameters that Twilio passes to my application.

## How would I properly retrieve the CallSid for incoming calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, the issue was been solved by simply using Ruby's `params` instead of the Twilio HTTP Request object:

> `puts params['CallSid']`